# Can't populate dropdown menu (options)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using spring MVC 4 and I am trying to populate a dropdown menu (select-options) but can't find a way to make it work (already spend hours).

Model:

```
public class DataFixingModel {
private ArrayList<String> keys;
private String value;
private String keySelected;


public dataFixingModel() {
    this.keys = getKeysValues(); //return ArrayList
    this.value = "TMP";
    this.keySelected = "abc";
}
....
public ArrayList<String> getKeys() {
    return keys;
}
....
```

Controller:

```
public class DataFixing {

@RequestMapping(value = "/extra/dataFixing/dataFixing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationTask(ModelMap model) throws ParseException {
    DataFixingModel dataFixingModel = new DataFixingModel();
    ArrayList<String> urls = dataFixingModel.getKeys();
    for (String str:urls){
        System.out.println("------key:"+str);
    }
    //it print all the keys as expected

    model.addAttribute("dataFixingModel", dataFixingModel);
    return "extra/dataFixing/dataFixing";
}
```

}

jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="dataFixingModel" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" cellspacing="2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
    ....
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form:select class="form-control input-sm" path="keySelected" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="${title}">
                    <form:option value="0">--Choose Identifier Type--</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${keys}"/>
                </form:select>
        </div>
```

1. "TMP" appears fine in the "value" field.
2. In other model-controller-jsp the dropdown is populated by the the requested key but not in the above model-controller-jsp.
3. I already tried to use array ([]) instead of arraylist).
4. In the view source there is no keys under the options.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Miki

Comment: you have public `getter` for attributes in `DataFixingModel`?

Comment: Yes. all the getters/setters are public...

Answer (score 0):

If you have this getter:

```
public ArrayList<String> getOpenUrlKeys() {
    return openUrlKeys;
}
```

You will get the content with `<form:options items="${openUrlKeys}"/>`

But does not make much sense because I can't see openUrlKeys variable declared... it should be `getKeys()` to use `<form:options items="${keys}"/>`

Comment: Sorry, the getter is: getKeys with the parameter keys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I replaced: `<form:options items="${keys}"/>`
with: `<form:options items="${dataFixingModel.keys}"/>`.

Thanks all!
Mike